# Problems in using minitoc

Tags: minitoc

My MWE,

```
\documentclass[oneside,a4paper,12pt]{book}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,amssymb}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{minitoc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}



\title{\Huge{\color{Red}{Sample Title}}}
\author{\textsc{\large{The Author}}}
\date{}
\frontmatter
\maketitle
\newpage
\vspace{8cm}
\newpage
\dominitoc
\tableofcontents
\mainmatter

\part{Sample Part}
\chapter{Sample Chapter}
\minitoc

\section{Sample Section}
\section*{Epilogue}
\end{document}
```

I have the following questions,

1. In the mini-table-of-contents the unnumbered section(s) (here it is the section named **Epilogue**) are not shown. How can I solve this problem?
2. What needs to be done to remove the space between the end of the mini-table-of-contents and the beginning of first section?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution

1. We need to use

---

```
\section*{Epilogue}
\addtocontents{toc}{\begingroup\protect\renewcommand\protect\contentsline[3]{}}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Epilogue}
\addtocontents{toc}{\endgroup}
```

**Edit** if `hyperref` is used it's `\contentsline[4]`

---

2. There is command `\mtcsetfeature{minitoc}{after}{\vspace{DIMEN}}`

---

**Complete code**

```
\documentclass[oneside,a4paper,12pt]{book}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,amssymb}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{minitoc}
\mtcsetfeature{minitoc}{after}{\vspace{-1cm}}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}

\title{\Huge{\color{Red}{Sample Title}}}
\author{\textsc{\large{The Author}}}
\date{}
\frontmatter
\maketitle
\newpage
\vspace{8cm}
\newpage
\dominitoc
\tableofcontents
\mainmatter
\part{Sample Part}
\chapter{Sample Chapter}
\minitoc

\section{Sample Section}
\section*{Epilogue}
\addtocontents{toc}{\begingroup\protect\renewcommand\protect\contentsline[3]{}}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Epilogue}
\addtocontents{toc}{\endgroup}
\end{document}
```